# Pspice for TI: inverter

Tags: pspice

I'm new on Pspice for TI and I'd like to know why is this very simple inverter not working? Any advice?

The simulation seems saturated it doesn't display the PWM signal on the gate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: U1 is connected upside-down. Swap the source and drain connections.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you but the simulator still doesn't display the square signal as on the picture above

Comment: Please update the schematic image if you changed the schematic. What is the value of VBUS?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I think I have a big problem because when a simulate only the square signal signal source  I got nothing, what the hell is that ?

Comment: Update the image to show the proper configuration as requested.

Comment: Do you need to put a .tran statement somewhere in the diagram to run the analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Working Circuit]

[image: Simulation results]

Two things:

1. Ensure your Vdd has a voltage source (vdc) connected to it.
2. The product page for the MOSFETs show the maximum voltages we can use with them. So avoid using anything 12 V or greater in magnitude. Hence I went with a safe 5 V.

Once those are fixed, run the simulation and voila.